# Pure imaginary roots

Tags: complex-analysis

Given

$\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(z+j)=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(1+j), z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Prove that such an equation does not have purely imaginary roots.

Unfortunately, I do not know any ways to prove the absence of purely imaginary roots other than substitute into the equation $i\cdot x, x \in \mathbb{R}$. Please, tell me what methods you think are applicable here.

Comment: My initial guess is to start from: if $ix$ is a roots, $-ix$ is a root (since it is a real polynomial equation,) and the polynomial on the left side must be divisible by $z^2+x^2.$ Not sure where to go from there.

Comment: One approach that works for small $n$ but I couldn't easily extend, is to look at what values of $x$ make the LHS real. EG for $n = 4$, the LHS is $(x^4 - 11x^2) + i(-6x^3 + 6x)$, so we have $-x^3 + 1 = 0$ with the only real solution $x = 1$ and the LHS is $1-11$ which is much smaller than $\prod (1+j) > 0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't follow what you're saying. At best, I have $ \prod(x^2 + j^2) =  \prod (ix+j)(-ix+j) = \prod(1+j)^2$  [But this is an equation, not an identity] or $\prod(ix + j) - \prod (-ix+j) = 0 $ (which leads to my comment).

Comment: I didn't say anything about $\prod(x^2+z^2),$ I said $z^2+x^2$ is a factor of the polynomial,. The polynomial is $\prod (z+i) -\prod(1+i).$

Comment: If $n=3,$ then this polynomial is $$z(1+z)(2+z)-1\cdot 2\cdot 3=z^3+3z^2+2z-6$$ and it needs to be divisible by $z^2+A$ where $A$ is a positive  real number